# Sort data after specific ordering (ascending/descending) in multiple columns

Tags: sorting

I have some data:

```
data={{"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 1, 2}, {"a", 1, 3}, 
      {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, 
      {"c", 3, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}}
```

When I use:

```
Sort[data]
```

I get the list ordered in incremental order first with column 1 then by 2 and last by the third.
Suppose I want the first column in increasing order but the second in decreasing order and the third again in increasing order. How do I do that?

I tried with `Sort` and `SortBy` but I haven't managed to make it work.

The output should be:

> a 3 2
>
> a 3 3
>
> a 1 1
>
> a 1 2
>
> a 1 3
>
> b 2 2
>
> b 2 3
>
> c 3 1
>
> c 2 1

Comment: An interesting variation of the usual and now boring sort-by-column question. +1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Caveat lector: Incorrect results are generated by this solution, e.g.,
>
> `sortByColumn[{{"a", 1, 1}, {"b", 2, 3}, {"a", 3, 2}}, {1, 1, -1}]`
>
> returns
>
> `{{"a", 1, 1}, {"b", 2, 3}, {"a", 3, 2}}`
>
> when the correct result is obviously
>
> `{{"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}}`
>
> I've commented on the answer to bring it to the attention of the author, 
>   however seeing as they've not been here in some time, I'm also putting this here: I think a highly upvoted and accepted answer needs to be correct. - [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao)

Here is my contribution, which has the following benefits over previous answers:

- It sorts both numbers and non-numeric structures
- You can sort any column (not just the first, followed by the second, etc)
- You can sort in either direction (ascending / descending)
- Original order is kept: if you sort on the second column, the first entry will follow the order of the original list. See the example with `{0,-1}`
- **Edit** also allow specifying the priority of the columns. So given `{-1,1}` for the ordering, you can specify `{1,2}` to give the higher *priority* to the second column.

The code is as follows, including my `usage` code for my own comments.

```
Clear[sortByColumn]
sortByColumn::usage = 
  "Arguments: [Table, Direction, Priority]. Returns the list sorted \
by the directions for each column specified in `Direction`. For \
ascending order, use `1`, and for descending order, use `-1`. For \
sorting more than one column, input `Direction` as a list. For \
example, Direction={-1,1} will sort the first column in descending \
order followed by the second column in ascending order, ignoring any \
other column. To sort on the second column, use {0,1} for the syntax.

  When sorting two or more columns, you can provide the `Priority` \
for which column should be sorted first. For example, \
`sortByColumn[data,{-1,1},{1,2}]` would sort first in ascending order \
on the second column (because it has a higher priority) and then in \
descending order on the first column.";

sortByColumn[list_?MatrixQ, dir : _Integer | {__Integer}, priority_: {}] := 
 Module[{l = Length@list[[1, All]], w, p, d},
  w = Reverse@Range@l;
  p = If[Length@priority > 0, PadRight[Flatten@{priority}, l], 
    p = Range@l];
  w = w[[Ordering@p]];
  d = PadRight[Flatten@{dir}, l];
  Sort[list, NonNegative@Total[(w d MapThread[Order, {##}])] &]]
```

For example, using the data set provided by Mr. Wizard:

```
data={{"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 1, 5}, {"a", 1, 3}, 
      {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, 
      {"c", 3, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}};
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] /. {1 -> "q", 2 -> "r", 3 -> "s"};
```

Here are the results of some trial runs. First the original:

```
{a,q,1}
{a,q,2}
{a,q,3}
{c,r,1}
{b,r,2}
{b,r,3}
{c,s,1}
{a,s,2}
{a,s,3}
```

The result of `sortByColumn[data,-1]`.

```
{c,r,1}
{c,s,1}
{b,r,2}
{b,r,3}
{a,q,1}
{a,q,2}
{a,q,3}
{a,s,2}
{a,s,3}
```

Result of `sortByColumn[data,{0,-1}]`

```
{c,s,1}
{a,s,2}
{a,s,3}
{c,r,1}
{b,r,2}
{b,r,3}
{a,q,1}
{a,q,2}
{a,q,3}
```

And finally, the result the OP wanted, `sortByColumn[data,{1,-1,1}]`

```
{a,s,2}
{a,s,3}
{a,q,1}
{a,q,2}
{a,q,3}
{b,r,2}
{b,r,3}
{c,s,1}
{c,r,1}
```

An example showing the use of the priority argument: `sortByColumn[data, {-1, 1}, {1, 2}]`

```
{a,q,1}
{a,q,5}
{a,q,3}
{c,r,1}
{b,r,2}
{b,r,3}
{c,s,1}
{a,s,2}
{a,s,3}
```

Comment: I would love to know if there is a handy way of checking is this a number or vector of numbers to check the second argument of my solution?

Comment: I don't know how efficient it is, but I don't see any problem. What I like is that it would be very easy to add a new parameter to change not only the direction of each sorting but the priority of columns (in your function it would mean building the `w` considering it).

Comment: Not sure about efficiency either, but I'm a bit confused as to what you mean about the priority of the columns. Oh, do you mean that given an ordering `{1,-1,1}` you could still specify a column designation `{1,0,2}` so that it sorts by the third column first, then the first, and then the second?

Comment: @FJRA is this version what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, it does! I was thinking about adding the priority as the number of columns instead of using a number to define ordering but that does the same trick.

Comment: Wow, this looks great.  I need time to try to understand this and test its performance.  To make this complete I suspect that it will be best to add definitions for simple cases that can be handled with `SortBy`, etc.  For: "is this a number or vector of numbers" try `dir : _Integer | {__Integer}`

Comment: That's what I was missing. I was trying dir/; IntegerQ || VectorQ, but I guess there's something about that test that I don't understand.

Comment: A warning to readers - this appears to get incorrect results under various conditions, e.g. `sortByColumn[{{2, 2, 1, 1}, {-2, -1, 2, -2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {-2, -1, 
   2, -2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {-2, -1, 2, -2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {-2, -1, 
   2, -2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {-2, -1, 2, -2}}, {-1, 1, -1}]` gets it wrong (matches neither an explicit `SortBy` or pulling via `Ordering` on the same data set).

Comment: @ciao I believe this is the first I have seen the caveat you edited in.  Shame on me for missing that, but before I look into this myself do you have a solution to correct this method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Yes, it may be the only time this kind of situation has arisen for me - I'd rather have had the OP note it/fix it, but as noted they seem to be gone and a reader seeing such an upvoted/accepted answer might get led down the rabbit hole. Feel free to remove it if you deem inappropriate. As to second part of query, yes. Tell you what, I'll post here as an answer for now for you to take and do with as you wish - it's a function I use but has much extra code to optimize cases that can be trimmed, I've no time to do so right now.

Comment: @ciao Is it known why this happens? What fix (as you mention) would correct it? Or is it a bug?

Comment: @TheVee - not a bug, doing what it's suppose to with the OP's code - in fact, when I read the code my first thought was "this won't work correctly", and after grabbing their code and running it, verified. Take a peek at my non-answer below for what I use.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to keep the rows and your preferences of ordering is first ascending, second descending and third ascending, you can use `SortBy`:

```
SortBy[data, {#[[1]],-#[[2]],#[[3]]}&]
```

Comment: :) now why didn't I think of that.. Easy points for you! Thx.

Comment: This only works on numeric data.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, it works only on numeric data, but I think it is the easiest way to be remember. Your generalization is very nice, but needs to be added to your personal package of utilities (something worth having).

Comment: Would love your opinion on the solution I posted below. Might see some error that I haven't.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Why does that work only on numerical data? I tried that on strings and it works well. Am i missing something?

Comment: @leosenko Please compare the output of `SortBy[Characters@{"anw", "aox", "apy", "bqz"}, {#[[1]], -#[[2]], #[[3]]} &]` to `f2[Characters@{"anw", "aox", "apy", "bqz"}, {1, -1, 1}]` (using `f2` from my answer) and see that the former does not reverse-sort by the second column as does the latter.

Answer (score 11):

FJRA's method is clever, but it will fail if the reverse-order column is non-numeric.

For example:

```
data={{"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 1, 5}, {"a", 1, 3}, 
      {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, 
      {"c", 3, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}};
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] /. {1 -> "q", 2 -> "r", 3 -> "s"};
```

---

#### New method

Here is a new method that I believe is a bit cleaner.

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]

f1[idx_, {d_, ir___}] :=
  Join @@ f1[idx + 1, {ir}] /@ 
    If[d == -1, Reverse, # &] @
      SplitBy[SortBy[#, #[[idx]] &], #[[idx]] &] &

f1[__] := Identity

f2[dat_?MatrixQ, dir_?VectorQ] := dat // f1[1, dir]
```

The second argument is a list of sort directions by column, `-1` representing reverse.

```
f2[data, {1, -1, 1}] // Column
```

> ```
> {a,s,2}
> {a,s,3}
> {a,q,1}
> {a,q,3}
> {a,q,5}
> {b,r,2}
> {b,r,3}
> {c,s,1}
> {c,r,1}
> ```

#### Old method

Preserved for reference, along with a bug fix.

I cannot think of a way to do this sort with arbitrary data outside of implementing my own sort function.  Something like this:

```
f1[idx_, {d_, ir___}, max_] /; idx <= max :=
  Reap[
    Sow[#, #[[idx]]] & ~Scan~ #,
    If[d == -1, Reverse, # &] @ Union @ #[[All, idx]],
    f1[idx + 1, {ir}, max][#2] &
  ][[2]] ~Flatten~ 2 &

f1[__] = Identity;

f2[dat_?MatrixQ, dir_?VectorQ] := dat // f1[1, dir, Dimensions[dat][[2]]]
```

That's none too pretty and I hope there is a cleaner way, but it eludes me.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @FJRA 's post and @Mr.Wizard 's comment, I come up with a direct way to solve it.

The key is to define a priority function which returns MMA comparible values for individual terms.
These values  *are not limited to be numbers*. As I quote from the documentation:

> SortBy[{$e_1,e_2,e_3$},...,f] sorts the $e_i$ so that the f[$e_i$] lie in canonical order.
>   If some of the f[$e_i$] are the same, then the canonical order of the corresponding $e_i$ is used.

So in order to sort string in a decending order, we have to rewrite it in a "reverse order" for individual characters.

Lets define a function as the following (only for unicode characters, one can easily generalize the code to deal with another characters)

```
reverseString[a_String] := FromCharacterCode[59391- ToCharacterCode@a]
```

we can sort the data by (decending, decending, ascending) order:

```
SortBy[data, {reverseString[#[[1]]], -#[[2]], #[[3]]} &]
(*==>
{{"c", 3, 1}, {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, {"a", 3,  2}, {"a", 3, 3}, {"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 1, 2}, {"a", 1, 3}}*)
```

or even for the case where strings are composed of many characters:

```
data2 = {{"aa", 1, 1}, {"ab", 1, 2}, {"ac", 1, 3}, {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, {"c", 3, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}};
SortBy[data, {reverseString[#[[1]]], -#[[2]], #[[3]]} &]
(*==>
{{"c", 3, 1}, {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, {"b", 2, 3}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}, {"ac", 1, 3}, {"ab", 1, 2}, {"aa", 1, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note to readers - this is not an answer, per se, but answer-ish responding to a query by Mr. Wizard, so *caveat lector*....

This is what I use for such things. Note there are chunks of code devoted to specific cases and optimizations that are not needed for purely numeric sort columns.

```
colsorter[data_, cols_, highdupes_: False] := Module[{td, td1, td2},
   If[MatrixQ[data[[All, Abs@Pick[cols, Sign@cols, -1]]], NumericQ],
    data[[
     Ordering[
      Transpose[Transpose@data[[All, Abs[cols]]]*Sign[cols]]]]],
    td = Transpose@data;
    data[[Ordering@Transpose[With[{td1 = td[[Abs@#]]},
           Sign[#] If[VectorQ[td1, NumericQ], td1, Replace[td1,

              AssociationThread[(td2 = 
                  If[highdupes, Sort@DeleteDuplicates@td1, 
                   Union@td1]) -> Range@Length@td2], {1}]]] & /@ 
         cols]]]]];
```

Arguments are the data to be sorted, the list of columns to sort by, and optional duplicate density flag.

Columns are listed as e.g. `(3,-2,4}`, meaning sort by columns 3, 2, and 4 in that order of priority, and with column 2 in reverse sort order.

Sorry for the brevity of exposition, a bit busy and as noted in the preamble, not a full answer.