# Numbering element in descending order

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I numbering the elements in descending order of second elements of sublists?
For example, if I have the list which is

```
m={{1, 5}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 9}, {6, 7}, {7, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 5}, {10, 2}};
```

The smallest second element is 2 of `{10,2}` so its number is 1.
Second smallest second element is also 2 of `{4,2}` so its number will be 2.
The output that I want is then: `{4, 6, 9, 2, 8, 5, 7, 10, 3, 1}`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please have a look at `SortBy`.

Answer (score 4):

Why you rank `{10, 2}` before `{4, 2}` escapes me.  Ignoring that:

```
m = {{1, 5}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 9}, {6, 7},
     {7, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 5}, {10, 2}};

m[[All, 2]] // Ordering // Ordering
```

> ```
> {3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 9, 10, 4, 2}
> ```

Equivalent: `Nest[Ordering, m[[All, 2]], 2]`

See [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html).

---

If we reverse `m` before and after we get:

```
Nest[Ordering, Reverse[m][[All, 2]], 2] // Reverse
```

> ```
>  {4, 6, 9, 2, 8, 5, 7, 10, 3, 1}
> ```

Comment: oh, I miss that part. If second element is same, I want to rank the sublists in ascending order of first element. Can you help me one more time please?

Comment: Sometimes, I wish they'd added an `OrderingBy[]` in complete analogy to `SortBy[]`...

Comment: @Sungjin, `Ordering[{{1, 5}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 9}, {6, 7}, {7, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 5}, {10, 2}}, All, If[Last[#1] != Last[#2], Last[#1] > Last[#2], First[#1] <= First[#2]] &]`

Comment: @SungjinLee take a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2934/121

Comment: @J.M. `orderingBy[list_, f_] := Ordering[{f@#, #} & /@ list]`

Comment: Two or more, use a... `Nest`? Dijkstra would be proud! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.0 there is [OrderingBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html):

```
m = {{1, 5}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 9}, {6, 7}, {7, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 5}, {10, 2}};

Ordering @ OrderingBy[Last] @ m
```

{3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 9, 10, 4, 2}