# How to sort my list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

For example I have two lists of such structure

```
L1 = {{"Australia",a1}, {"USA",a2}, {"Norway",a3},...}
L2 = {{"Russia",b1}, {"Norway",b2}, {"Japan",b3},...}
```

I would like to sort countries of the list `L2` in the countries' order of `L1` to compare it entirely (I mean the values matching for each country). Thus I would like to gain something resembling this as a result where `L3` is the sorted `L2`:

```
L1 = {{"Australia",a1}, {"USA",a2}, {"Norway",a3},...}
L3 = {{"Australia",b26},{"USA",b13} {"Norway",b2},...}
```

Comment: Contries are the same for sure.

Comment: Related: [(13886)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13886/121), [(22599)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22599)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1 = {{"a", a1}, {"b", a2}, {"c", a3}}
l2 = {{"c", b3}, {"b", b2}, {"a", b1}}
{#, # /. Rule @@@ l2} &[l1[[All, 1]]] // Transpose
(*
   {{"a", b1}, {"b", b2}, {"c", b3}}
*)
```

Comment: That's why taking `l1 = {{"a", a1}, {"c", a3}, {"b", a2}};` would be a better example :)

Answer (score 4):

*Edit:* This question closely related to one asked on Stack Overflow before the existence of Mathematica.SE.  Please see this link for the history and examples:

- [Unsort: remembering a permutation and undoing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545223/618728)

See also:

- [Ordering@Ordering and Ranking Permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4742772/618728)

The first Q&A references a use of the `Ordering` method shown below from 2007 on MathGroup:

- http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html

(Thanks to belisarius for helping me find this.)

---

From your declaration "Contries(sic) are the same for sure." follows:

```
L1 = {{"IsleOfMan", 1}, {"Samoa", 2}, {"Tunisia", 3}, {"Svalbard", 4}, {"NewCaledonia", 5}};
L2 = {{"Tunisia", 1}, {"NewCaledonia", 2}, {"IsleOfMan", 3}, {"Svalbard", 4}, {"Samoa", 5}};

GatherBy[L1 ~Join~ L2, First][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{"IsleOfMan", 3}, {"Samoa", 5}, {"Tunisia", 1}, {"Svalbard", 4}, {"NewCaledonia", 2}}
> ```

Or correcting eldo's attempt as using `Ordering`:

```
Sort[L2][[Ordering @ Ordering @ L1]]
```

> ```
> {{"IsleOfMan", 3}, {"Samoa", 5}, {"Tunisia", 1}, {"Svalbard", 4}, {"NewCaledonia", 2}}
> ```

Both are much faster than belisarius's method, with `Ordering` being particularly good:

*Edit:* Now including Simon Woods' recommendation from the comments as `sim`.

```
bel[{l1_, l2_}] := {#, # /. Rule @@@ l2} &[l1[[All, 1]]] // Transpose

wiz[{L1_, L2_}] := GatherBy[L1 ~Join~ L2, First][[All, 2]]

ord[{L1_, L2_}] := Sort[L2][[Ordering @ Ordering @ L1]];

sim[{L1_, L2_}] := L2[[ Ordering[L2][[Ordering @ Ordering @ L1]] ]]

gen[n_] := Table[{RandomSample @ Range @ n, Range @ n}\[Transpose], {2}]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{bel, wiz, ord, sim}, gen, 2^Range[20],
  "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1*^-6, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: For small data it is a little faster to use `L2[[Ordering[L2][[Ordering@Ordering@L1]]]]`

Comment: @Simon That's a lot of `Ordering`!  Let me add it to the timings. :-)

Comment: @Simon `BenchmarkPlot` doesn't seem to show much difference.  Can you give me an example where the difference is more apparent?

Comment: Hmm, I saw a fairly consistent difference for small n but after a restart it has gone away!

Comment: Interesting! Now we need to find 10^5 countries to try it out.

Comment: @belisarius LOL -- touche.  I always take examples and merely that, assuming application to other, larger problems, but if the OP really only wants this for working with country names any of these methods will do fine.

Comment: T'was a joke, of course. I didn't worry about the performance just because I was thinking narrowly. It's always better to be able to see the forest. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
L1 = {{"Australia", a1}, {"USA", a2}, {"Norway", a3}};
L2 = {{"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}, {"Australia", b3}};

L2[[Flatten[Position[First /@ L2, #] & /@ First /@ L1]]]
```

> {{"Australia", b3}, {"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}}

Or (revised as per Mr. Wizard's comments)

```
Sort[L2][[Ordering @ Ordering @ L1]]
```

> {{"Australia", b3}, {"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}}

Comment: Unfortunately `Sort[L2][[Ordering[L1]]]` does not appear to work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard With me it produces the output shown in my answer. Please clarify

Comment: Actually I just remembered something; *THIS* does work: `Sort[L2][[Ordering @ Ordering @ L1]]`, and I think it will help me find my elusive duplicate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I updated

Comment: I still can't find the duplicate; the only use of double `Ordering` I can find at the moment is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13887/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps the comment under this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31266/193

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! If I had bothered to take a closer look at the linked comment I would have seen the link to this: [(4545223)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545223) which is exactly what I was looking for!  I have to remember that some of these questions were from that long ago.  No point in looking for the duplicate on *this* site!

Comment: @belisarius Since you answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742965/618728) question yourself so long ago I'm a little disappointed you didn't use that method here.  I guess no one is perfect. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The only Perfect one is Ford. You're welcome.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard BTW, Did you delete your question about incompabilities between V7 and V10? Can't find it anymore

Comment: @eldo It's still there: [(56728)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728).  The title is unchanged but I did edit the bold line in the body; perhaps you were searching on a phrase in that.  You can mark a question as a favorite if you worry about it getting lost; that way it will always be there in your profile even if the title or body are edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
L1 = {{"Australia", a1}, {"Norway", a2}, {"USA", a3}, {"Russia", a4}, {"Japan", a5}} ;
L2 = {{"Russia", b1}, {"Norway", b2}, {"Japan", b3}};

x = First /@ L1;

y = Cases[L2, {#, _}] & /@ x;

z = Apply[Sequence, y, {2}] /. {} -> "";

Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{L1, z}], {"L1", "L3"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit**

For speed, create `y` like so :--

```
getSubset[input_List, sub_List] := Module[{test},
  (test@# = True) &~Scan~sub;
  Apply[Sequence, Reap[Cases[input, x : {y_?test, ___} :> x~Sow~y], sub][[2]], {2}]] 

y = getSubset[L2, x]
```

**Timing Tests**

```
test = Range[10000];
L1 = Transpose[{test, test}];
L2 = RandomSample[L1, 10000];

Row[{First@Timing[x = First /@ L1;
    y = Cases[L2, {#, _}] & /@ x;
    z = Apply[Sequence, y, {2}] /. {} -> ""], " seconds"}]
```

> 46.457098 seconds

```
Row[{First@Timing[x = First /@ L1;
    y = getSubset[L2, x];
    z = Apply[Sequence, y, {2}] /. {} -> ""], " seconds"}]
```

> 0.124801 seconds

```
Row[{First@Timing[
    {#, # /. Rule @@@ L2} &[L1[[All, 1]]]], " seconds"}]
```

> 1.372809 seconds

```
Row[{First@Timing[
    L2[[Flatten[Position[First /@ L2, #] & /@ First /@ L1]]]], " seconds"}]
```

> 5.163633 seconds

Answer (score 1):

`SortBy[l2, Position[l1, #1 [[1]]] [[1, 1]] &]`

Comment: There's no need to extract the number from the position result: `SortBy[l2, Position[l1, First@#]&]`

Answer (score 1):

While there are a number of replies with ways of ordering the two lists, let me give a different approach to comparing two sets of data of the form you gave. This applies if you are using v10 as it uses `Associations`.

Here's the data eldo used

```
l1 = {{"Australia", a1}, {"USA", a2}, {"Norway", a3}};
l2 = {{"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}, {"Australia", b3}};
```

Construct two `Associations`:

```
{assoc1, assoc2} = (Association[Rule @@@ #] & /@ {l1, l2})

(*
{<|"Australia" -> a1, "USA" -> a2, "Norway" -> a3|>, <|"USA" -> b1, 
  "Norway" -> b2, "Australia" -> b3|>}
*)
```

The advantage is that you can now use the countries as keys, and there is no need to worry about ordering. Here are the keys:

```
Keys@assoc1
(*{"Australia", "USA", "Norway"}*)
```

Here is one way to check all of them for equality:

```
{#, assoc1[#] == assoc2[#]} & /@ Keys[assoc1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica 10's associations makes this simple.

```
l1 = {{"Australia", a1}, {"USA", a2}, {"Norway", a3}, {"Russia", a4}, {"Japan", a5}};
```

Convert the second list to an association

```
l2 = Association@((#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) & /@ {{"Russia", b1}, {"Norway", b2}, {"Japan", b3}, {"Australia", b4}, {"USA", b5}});
```

Apply the association rules

```
l3 = ReplaceAll[l1, {x_, y_} :> {x, l2[x]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup is working also.

```
    l1 = {{"Australia", a1}, {"USA", a2}, {"Norway", a3}};
    l2 = {{"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}, {"Australia", b3}};
    {First@#, Lookup[Rule @@@ l2, First@#]} & /@ l1
```

or

```
    {#, Lookup[Rule @@@ l2, #]} & /@ l1[[;; , 1]]

    (*{{"Australia", b3}, {"USA", b1}, {"Norway", b2}}*)
```