# Multicolumn sorting with ordering functions and precedence

Tags: dataset, sorting

I am aware that the question of "how do I sort on a column" has been asked in various forms, most notably [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/sort-per-column).  While some powerful solutions have been presented, as far as I can find no one solution brings together all the elements of what most users would expect from a multi-column sort, similar to what one would find in Excel or SQL.  The sought solution would:

- Work equally well with matrices, lists of associations, or `Dataset` objects
- Allow one to choose multiple existing or calculated columns, in a set precedence order
- Allow one to independently set the comparison function for each column, at minimum ascending vs. descending

The fact that this question has been asked (and answered) in so many forms is a collective expression of surprise that this seemingly simple action should not have a more elegant solution built in.  This should not be so hard in a language that can give us so much power, usually in a single line of code.

I will put my own solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica provides the sorting function `Sort` and `SortBy`.  `Sort` has a second argument  that allows us to pass a function that compares two elements.  `SortBy` has a second argument that lets us calculate a value (or calculate a list of values) to sort by, but does not let us provide the comparison function.  There does not appear to be a straightforward way to combine these two.

Borrowing the example data from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/sort-per-column),

```
data = {{"a", 1, 1}, {"a", 1, 2}, {"a", 1, 3}, {"c", 2, 1}, {"b", 2, 2}, 
{"b", 2, 3}, {"c", 3, 1}, {"a", 3, 2}, {"a", 3, 3}};
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] /. {1 -> "q", 2 -> "r", 3 -> "s"};
assoc = AssociationThread[{"first", "second", "third"} -> #] & /@ data

(* {<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 1|>, <|"first" -> "a", 
"second" -> "q", "third" -> 2|>, <|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", 
"third" -> 3|>, <|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "r", 
"third" -> 1|>, <|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", 
"third" -> 2|>, <|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", 
"third" -> 3|>, <|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "s", 
"third" -> 1|>, <|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", 
"third" -> 2|>, <|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 3|>} *)
```

The second argument to `SortBy` can be used to select columns

```
SortBy[{#first &, #third &}][assoc]

(* {<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 1|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 2|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 2|>,
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 3|>,
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 3|>, 
<|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 2|>, 
<|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 3|>, 
<|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 1|>, 
<|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 1|>} *)
```

but no way to choose the function by which these are ordered column by column.

The approach I use here is to use `GroupBy` to create a tree of associations with common values in each column.  Then I do a depth-first traversal, sorting by the keys and unpacking the results until the table is sorted.  First, I have to make a new version of `KeySort` that lets me set the comparison function as in `Sort`:

```
keySort[assoc_Association, p_: (OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &)] := 
 Query[Ordering[Keys[assoc], All, p]]@assoc
```

The function `orderby` groups the data by column values and performs the depth-first traversal:

```
orderby[dat_, f_, p_] := Module[{len = Length[p]},
  Fold[
   Function[{aa, pp}, 
    Map[Flatten[Values[keySort[#, pp]], 1] &, aa, {--len}]],
   GroupBy[dat, f],
   Reverse[p]
   ]
  ]
```

The rest of the code provides a more Mathematica-idosyncratic interface.  The complete code is here:

```
Ascending::usage = 
  "Ascending is the default ordering function for OrderBy, sorting \
the corresponding column into canonical order.";
Descending::usage = 
  "Descending is an ordering function for OrderBy, sorting the \
corresponding column into reverse canonical order.";

keySort::usage = 
  "keySort[assoc, p] orders the elements of an association by sorting \
its keys using the ordering function p.";

OrderBy::usage = 
  "OrderBy[f][list] sorts the elements of list in the order defined \
by applying f to each of them.

  OrderBy[f, p][list] sorts using the ordering function p.

  OrderBy[{f1, f2, ...}, {p1, p2, ...}][list] sorts using the \
ordering function pi for the corresponding fi.";

Ascending = OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &;
Descending = OrderedQ[{#2, #1}] &;

keySort[assoc_Association, p_: (OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &)] := 
 Query[Ordering[Keys[assoc], All, p]]@assoc

orderby[dat_, f_, p_] := Module[{len = Length[p]},
  Fold[
   Function[{aa, pp}, 
    Map[Flatten[Values[keySort[#, pp]], 1] &, aa, {--len}]],
   GroupBy[dat, f],
   Reverse[p]
   ]
  ]

OrderBy[fi_, pi_: Automatic][dat_] := Module[{f, p},
  f = If[MatchQ[fi, _List], fi, {fi}];
  p = If[MatchQ[pi, _List],
     PadRight[pi, Length[f], Automatic],
     ConstantArray[pi, Length[f]]
     ] /. Automatic -> Ascending;
  orderby[dat, f, p]
  ]
```

`OrderBy` is an operator.  For example, to sort the example association in descending order by the first column then ascending order in the third:

```
OrderBy[{#first &, #third &}, {Descending, Ascending}]@assoc

(* {<|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 1|>, 
<|"first" -> "c", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 1|>, 
<|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 2|>, 
<|"first" -> "b", "second" -> "r", "third" -> 3|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 1|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 2|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 2|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "q", "third" -> 3|>, 
<|"first" -> "a", "second" -> "s", "third" -> 3|>} *)
```

The solution also works with matrix data.  The example below sorts the matrix data ascending by column 2 then descending by column 1, showing two different ways to choose the sorting columns (using `Extract` or `Query`)

```
OrderBy[{Extract[2], Query[1]}, {Ascending, Descending}]@data

(* {{"a", "q", 1}, {"a", "q", 2}, {"a", "q", 3}, {"c", "r", 1}, {"b", 
  "r", 2}, {"b", "r", 3}, {"c", "s", 1}, {"a", "s", 2}, {"a", "s", 3}} *)
```

Sadly, `OrderBy` does not always work with `Dataset`.  I am not sure why at this point. If I figure this out I will update the post.