# Breaking term order ties

Tags: sorting, order

I am interested in creating a table with positive Gaussian integers listed in order based on their norms, with ties broken by lex order.

So far I have `Sort[Flatten[Table[{a, b, a^2 + b^2}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}], 1], #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &], 1]`, which gives me some Gaussian integers sorted by norm, but the ties are broken in revlex.

For example, the code gives {1,0,1},{0,1,1} as the first nonzero entries, but I want those to be reversed.  A second application of Sort destroys the first Sort, so I need to be more clever, and alas I am not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of: [(9840)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9840/121) but I shall wait for confirmation from Trevor before closing.

Comment: That is a general situation that would solve my problem.  I was searching for things like "term order", so I didn't come up with that post.

Comment: So the output below is correct, and the matter is solved to your satisfaction?

Comment: Related: [(2934)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2934/121)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax errors but I think this is what you want:

```
list = Flatten[Table[{a, b, a^2 + b^2}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}], 1];

SortBy[list, #[[3]] &]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 4}, {2, 0, 4}, {1,
>   2, 5}, {2, 1,    5}, {2, 2, 8}, {0, 3, 9}, {3, 0, 9}, {1, 3, 10}, {3,
>   1, 10}, {2, 3, 13}, {3, 2, 13}, {0,    4, 16}, {4, 0, 16}, {1, 4, 17},
>   {4, 1, 17}, {3, 3, 18}, {2, 4, 20}, {4, 2, 20}, {0, 5,    25}, {3, 4,
>   25}, {4, 3, 25}, {5, 0, 25}, {1, 5, 26}, . . .}

With this syntax ties are (automatically) broken using the default ordering function.

Comment: That certainly does what I was hoping for.  I just wish I understood the inner workings.  I use Mathematica so rarely that I lose anything I learn during the few times a year I use it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor Please read the documentation for `SortBy`.  If you still have questions post them here as comments and I shall try to answer them later today.