# SortBy second item in each list item

Tags: core-language

I have:

```
mydata = {{1, "NEBRASKA", 2.7`}, {2, "NORTH DAKOTA", 3.`}, {3, "UTAH",
    3.6`}, {3, "VERMONT", 3.6`}, {5, "HAWAII", 3.7`}}
```

Now, I can do:

```
SortBy[mydata,First]
```

And:

```
SortBy[mydata,Last]
```

But how do I sort by the second item in each list?

Comment: `SortBy[mydata,#[[2]]&]`

Comment: `SortBy[mydata, First@*Rest]` :P

Comment: With version-10 operator forms: `mydata // SortBy@Extract@2`

Comment: Related: [(2934)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2934/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard et al, thanks everyone. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SortBy[mydata,#[[2]]&]
```

the supplied function should select the second element of each entry as the sort-by value.